# In Mongoose, how to aggregate references in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections:

People collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   name: String,
   employments: [
      {
         start: Date,
         end: Date
      }
   ]
}
```

Hours collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   people: ObjectId,
   workDate: Date,
   workHours: Number
}
```

In my Mongoose/Express controller, how can I create a new field **totalHrs** in each employments object to be returned with findById where it's a sum of hours.workHours where the workDate is between start and end in employments? e.g. something like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   name: String,
   employments: [
      {
         start: Date,
         end: Date,
         totalHrs: Number /*(Sum of hours.workHours)*/
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and learning, I solved it myself.

I did it with:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from:"hours",
            localField:"_id",
            foreignField:"people",
            as:"hours"
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind:"$hours"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            isInRange: {$and: [
                {$lt: ["$employments.start", "$hours.workDate"]},
                {$gte: ["$employments.end", "$hours.workDate"]},
                ]
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        $match: {"isInRange":true},
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: {$first: "$name"},
            totalHours: {$sum: "$hours.workHours"},
        }
    }

]);
```